# swing clicking two buttons

Tags: java, swing, button, compiler-errors, listeners

In my program there are two buttons and you have to click both of them in order for a system print out to happen. i am having trouble trying to achieve this though.

```
button[0].addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            button[0].setEnabled( false );
            if( button[1].isEnabled( false) );
                System.out.println("you clicked both buttons");
        }
    });
    button[1].addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            button[1].setBackground(Color.YELLOW);
            button[1].setEnabled( false );
            if( buttons[0].isEnabled( false) );
            System.out.println("you clicked both buttons");
        }
    });
```

I am getting errors in the line:

```
if( buttons[0].isEnabled( false) );
```

saying

```
The method isEnabled() in the type Component is not applicable for the arguments (boolean)
```

I am only a beginner in this so it would be great if someone could help or tell me another way to do this.

Comment: 1) For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/). 2) *"in my program there are two buttons and you have to click both of them in order for a system print"*  ***Why?***  Or rather, why not have a single `Print` button?

Comment: in my final program it will not create a system print, it will open a popup box. But at the moment this is what i have gotten to. Btw it is for an assingment which requires that there is two buttons and you have to click both of them.

Comment: *"Btw it is for an assingment which requires that there is two buttons"*  I find that hard to believe.  Can you copy/paste the part where you think it says that?  I suspect they mean something different.

Answer (score 3):

Exception is very clear. `isEnabled()` hasn't got parameters so you should use it in this way `buttons[0].isEnabled()`.

Answer (score 2):

`isEnabled` does not require an argument.

Do this:

```
if( buttons[0].isEnabled() )
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is your answer:

```
button1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {

        button1.setEnabled(false);
        if (!button1.isEnabled() && !button2.isEnabled()) {
            System.out.println("you clicked both buttons");
        }
    }
});

button2.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

        button2.setBackground(Color.YELLOW);
        button2.setEnabled(false);
        if (!button2.isEnabled() && !button1.isEnabled()) {
            System.out.println("you clicked both buttons");
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: You have several issues in your code, first don't put semicolons after if statements, second isEnabled() method doesn't take an argument it returns true or false, use ! to invert.